# Array is blank when creating from entries in a column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

This code creates an array off a range.

When I try to see if the array is saving the elements, by using `Debug.Print`, nothing is shown in the Immediate Window. It displays blank spaces. There are no errors.

This only happens in that part of the code, the first `Debug.Print` line works. I do have data in the columns.

```vb
Dim myArray() As Variant 
Dim iCountLI As Long 
Dim iElementLI As Long 

If IsEmpty(Range("B3").Value) = True Then
    ReDim myArray(0, 0)
Else
    iCountLI = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row
    iCountLI = (Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row) - 2 
    Debug.Print iCountLI
    ReDim myArray(iCountLI) 

    For iElementLI = 1 To iCountLI 
        myArray(iElementLI - 1) = Cells(iElementLI + 2, 2).Value 
        Debug.Print myArray(iElementLI)
    Next iElementLI
      
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediate problem: `ReDim myArray(iCountLI)` creates an array with *empty* values. In the For Loop, `myArray(iElementLI - 1) = Cells(iElementLI + 2, 2).Value` overwrites the *first, second, etc.* values, yet your `Debug.Print myArray(iElementLI)` is printing the *second, third, etc.* values. These, of course, haven't yet been overwritten, so they are still empty. The easiest fix, then, is to use `Debug.Print myArray(iElementLI - 1)`.

More generally, I think you might be misunderstanding the meaning of `ReDim myArray(iCountLI)`. Let's assume we have values in `B3:B7`. This would lead to `ReDim myArray(5)` in your code, but this is an array with **6** empty values, at location **0**,1,2,3,4,5. This means you will keep an empty value trailing in the array after your loop, which is probably not what you want.

Here's a suggested rewrite with some comments:

```
Sub FillArray()

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim iCountLI As Long
Dim iElementLI As Long

'let's assume: B3:B7 with values: 1,2,3,4,5

If IsEmpty(Range("B3").Value) = True Then
    ReDim myArray(0, 0)
Else
    'iCountLI = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row
    'this line serves no purpose: you are immediately reassigning the value in the next line
    
    'iCountLI = (Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row) - 2   'This would be 5,
                                                    'but myArray(5) would have SIX elements
    iCountLI = (Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row) - 3
    
    Debug.Print iCountLI '4
    
    ReDim myArray(iCountLI)
    
    'For iElementLI = 1 To iCountLI
    For iElementLI = 0 To iCountLI '0 to 4
    
    myArray(iElementLI) = Cells(iElementLI + 3, 2).Value    'starting at 0, so "+3", not "+2"
    'myArray(iElementLI - 1) = Cells(iElementLI + 2, 2).Value
    
    Debug.Print myArray(iElementLI) 'in succession: 1,2,3,4,5
    Next iElementLI
      
End If

End Sub
```

Finally, it is worth pointing out that you don't actually need a For Loop to populate an array with values from a range. You could use something as follows:

```
Sub FillArrayAlt()

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim iCountLI As Long
Dim iElementLI As Long

Dim myRange As Range

'let's assume: B3:B7 with values: 1,2,3,4,5

If IsEmpty(Range("B3").Value) = True Then
    ReDim myArray(0, 0)
Else
    
    Set myRange = Range("B3:" & Range("B3").End(xlDown).Address)
    myArray = Application.Transpose(myRange.Value)
    
    'N.B. Confusingly, used in this way, your array WILL start at 1!
    
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Debug.Print i; ":"; myArray(i)
        
'        1 : 1
'        2 : 2
'        3 : 3
'        4 : 4
'        5 : 5
        
    Next i
      
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are valuing `myArray(iElementLI -1)` and printing `myArray(iElementLI`), which is still empty.